# Signals during mainwindow.close()

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a mainwindow and from that I call another window,
I want the a a slot to get executed when the second window is closed. Is there any way to do that?

```
new_window = secondWindow()
new_window.show()
new_window.closed.connect(self.another function)
```

Is there any signal defined like this, or is there some other way to do that without closing the main window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to create a custom signal, and emit this signal in the `closeEvent` method:

```
class secondWindow(WidgetClass):
    closed = pyqtSignal()
    [...]

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closed.emit()
        WidgetClass.closeEvent(self, event)
```

Answer (score -1):

**simple solution**

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), MainWindow.close)
```

Comment: Your code closes the window when the button is pressed, but the OP requirement is different, he wants to be notified when the window closes by any means. I recommend you re-read the question. :-)

Comment: Yes, I have to agree with @eyllanesc. But thank you for your contribution.